# jQuery regular expression for decimal [17, 2]

Tags: javascript, jquery, decimal

I'd like to check number what it is decimal [17, 2] (0~17 and 0~2).

What is the regular expression for a decimal [17,2]?

For example

```
1
0.01
0.1
12345678901234567.01
...
```

I used `var regexp = /^\d+(?:\.\d\d?)?$/;` but it can be over 17.

Comment: This makes no sense at all, could you please clear things up with expected input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, your regex doesn't include the 17 limit anywhere.

The regex for "0 to 17 digits" will be:

```
\d{0,17}
```

You can read more on repetitions here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html